# GDB - Print floating point value from assembly

Tags: floating-point, linker, gdb, nasm

I have the following code, where `b` is initialized to the floating point value **123.45**:

```
global _start

section .data

    ;a : dw 999     ; declare word
    b : dq 123.45  ; declare quad word (double precision)

section .bss

    res : resq 1   ; reserve 1 quad word for result

section .text

    _start :

        nop
```

I create an object (sanityTest.o) file and an executable file (sanityTest) as follows. I am running on a x64 machine:

```
nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g sanityTest.asm -o sanityTest.o

ld -m elf_x86_64 -o sanityTest sanityTest.o
```

I then attempt to read the value of `b` in gdb as follows:

```
(gdb) file sanityTest
Reading symbols from sanityTest...done.
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
(gdb) run
Starting program:
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000b0 in _start ()
(gdb) print b
$1 = -858993459
(gdb) print/f b
$2 = -107374184
(gdb)
```

Why does neither `print b` nor `print/f b` display the value **123.45**?

**More information:**

If I compile the code with the line `b : dq 123.45` commented out, and the line `a : dw 999` uncommented, I am able to print the integer value of `a` of **999**:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = 999
```

If I compile with both lines uncommented, I can print neither `a` nor `b`. The value for `b` is the same gibberish as before, and I have no idea what is now being printed for `a`:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = -858979353
(gdb) p b
$2 = -858993459
(gdb) p/f a
$3 = -107487032
(gdb) p/f b
$4 = -107374184
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch I get the same value as `p b`

Comment: Try `print {double} &b`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That works! Why does it work, what do the brackets mean? Also what do I type in the third case to see the value of `a`? `p {double} &a` gives a "cannot access memory at address" error.

Comment: Try `print {short} &a`. I'll have to look at the source to be sure, which means not until Monday, but `{foo}` is equivalent to `*(foo *)`. Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Expressions).

Comment: Hmm, that link isn't positioning itself right. Look in the Expressions section. I'll put all this in an answer if the command to print `a` works for you.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Whoa, that also works! Thank you, I'm surprised `p {int} &a` doesn't work given that I used `dw` to reserve 16 bits. If you write up your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `p {int} &a` wouldn't work because `int`is 4 bytes. dw is 2-bytes so part of the value you are printing is the value at `a` and 2 bytes from `b`. The debugger didn't know you defined the data at label `a`  to be 2 bytes. You need to print the proper size yourself.

Comment: Ah ok, I see thanks!